# Assigning JavaScript variables to Django rendered variables in template files

Tags: javascript, django-templates

```html
<state data-value="{{ state }}"></state>
```

In my JavaScript file I have :

```js
var state = document.getElementsByTagName('state')[0].getAttribute('data-value');
```

In the past this was done because of XHTML1.1 spec - what is the correct approach in today's times ?
`<div data-value="{{ state }}"></div>` ?
We could also do in the html template `<script>var state = '{{ state }}';<script>` but I have like a bunch of such assignments.

How else can we mass-assign JavaScript variables pushed in the HTML template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add something like this in the Django view context:

```
"MY_VARIABLES": json.dumps({
    "state": "My state",
    "number": 40,
    "isActive": True,
    ...
})
```

And in the template assign only one variable and just use the values as object properties:

```
var MY_VARIABLES = {{ MY_VARIABLES|safe }};
```

> `MY_VARIABLES.state`

`'My state'`

> `MY_VARIABLES.number`

`40`

> `MY_VARIABLES.isActive`

`true`